# Настройки Maven в Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, maven

Доброго времени суток. 
В Idea, при создании нового проекта, всегда по умолчанию идет maven, встроенный в саму Idea. А мне он не нужен, поэтому каждый раз приходится вручную указывать папку со скачанной версией maven. Есть ли способ настроить программу так, что по умолчанию будет идти тот maven, что я сам скачал?

Answer (score 0):

File -> Other Settings -> Default Settings...
Там меняете как вам хочется и всё.